# Is it possible to streamline the logic in this?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a visualized way of seeing an inventory list. There are around 200 items and I am trying to format the diagrams to show green if we have a surplus of the item, yellow if we only have one set and red if we are out of stock. This is my first project with VBA and gleaned what I could from Google results. This is what I have so far, where I have the first item (it's a shape on the diagram named "1". Cell C2 is formatted to show either "Order", "1 Set" or "In Stock" based on another cell's value for the actual number on hand.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = "1 Set" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbYellow
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.Transparency = 0.75
        End If
    
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = "In Stock" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.Transparency = 0.75
        End If
    
        If ActiveSheet.Range("C2") = "Order" Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("1").Fill.Transparency = 0.75
        End If
```

And it just goes on from there. It was working perfectly for me until I got about halfway through and began getting errors for its size. So is there a way to have a main function system that can look at each of the items and apply it to the respective shape? Or, is there a way to break it into sections so each sub is smaller, but still behaves as a single process? Thank You!

Comment: Look into `Select Case` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Comment: One basic refactoring rule: find out code duplication, then extract it.  In your code, ``ActiveSheet.Shapes("1")`` and ``ActiveSheet.Range("C2")`` are repeated many times, so it is better to use variables to avoid the duplication.

Comment: How does it "go on" ?  C3/"2" etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim clr as long,  c As Range
     
    'Me is the sheet with this code
    For Each c in Me.Range("C2:C100").Cells 'for example     
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "1 Set": clr = vbYellow
            Case "In Stock": clr = vbGreen
            Case "Order": clr = vbRed
            Case Else: clr = vbWhite
        End Select
        Me.Shapes(CStr(c.Row-1)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
    Next c
End sub
```